# Link between LDP and convergence

Tags: probability-theory

Let $(P_n)$ a sequence of probability measures on a Polish space $X$, and assume it follows a LDP with speed (let's say) $n$ and good rate function $I:X\to [0,+\infty]$.

Does it imply some kind of convergence of the sequence $(P_n)$ ? With some additional conditions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the rate function.

Note that $\{x:I(x)\le\delta\}$ is nonempty for all $\delta>0$ (otherwise $1=P_n(X)\le e^{-n\delta+o(n)}\to0$), so since $I$ is a good rate function the Cantor intersection theorem implies that $I(x_0)=0$ for some $x_0\in X$.

If this $x_0$ is unique, then $P_n\Rightarrow\delta_{x_0}$ weakly. In fact, given a sequence $(Z_n)$ of $X$-valued random variables defined on the same probability space, with $P_n$ the law of $Z_n$, we have $Z_n\to x_0$ almost surely. To see this, let $U$ be an open neighborhood of $x_0$. Note that $\varepsilon:=\inf_{x\in X\setminus U}I(x)>0$ using a similar compactness argument to the above. This implies $\mathbb P(Z_n\in U^c)\le\exp(-n\varepsilon+o(n))$ which is summable, so almost sure convergence follows by the Borel-Cantelli lemma.

If $\{x:I(x)=0\}$ has more than one element, we no longer have convergence. We still have tightness - in fact, we have exponential tightness - but there may be more than one weak limit. For an example, take $X=\{-1,0,+1\}$, and let $P_n\{(-1)^n\}=1-P_n\{(-1)^{n+1}\}=\frac13$. Clearly $\{P_n\}$ does not converge, but it satisfies an LDP with good rate function $I(1)=I(-1)=0$, $I(0)=+\infty$.